# Android why doesn't activity finish

Tags: android

I have a problem with my game - when the live is 0 it should show the game-over screen and finish the game-activity, but the screen freezes instead.
The code in the surface is:

```
if(live <= 0){
        try {
            gameThread.setGameRunning(false);
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        gameOverHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gameOver.onGameOver(score);
            }
        });

    }
```

And the Interface in the GameActivity:

```
@Override
public void onGameOver(int score) {
    Intent gameOver = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
    gameOver.putExtra("score", score);
    startActivity(gameOver);
    gameEngine.stop();
    this.finish();
}
```

The Game-thread loops the canvas drawing and the Engine the movements of the Characters.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: A possibility is gameOverHandler wasn't created on UI thread but on a background thread. In that case the post will not take the execution to UI thread and finish may not have appropriate effect. Try creating gameOverHandler on UI thread using new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) and try if it works.

Comment: I've understand what you meaning and it's correct because in the surface gameOver is never assigned but how i must do it i don't understand what you mean with -->Looper.getMainlooper() can you descripe it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have initialised gameOverHandler somewhere in the code using

```
gameOverHandler = new Handler();
```

or

```
gameOverHandler = new GameOverHandler();
```

Try replacing it with

```
gameOverHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

or

```
gameOverHandler = new GameOverHandler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

depending on what class you have actually used.

Comment: Thank you but it does'nt work... i found a solution i don't have declared that the interface is in the UI..

Comment: Nice! If you could post the correct solution and mark it. The future users will be helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sry my internet was down about the weekend i've solved it with the constructor

```
public GameSurface(Context context, OnGameOver onGameOver){
...
}
```

and in the MainActivity

```
gameSurface = new GameSurface(this, this);
```

and implementing OnGameOver
a litte bit rewrite for my code but its works...